# How do you sort by Cell Color in Excel using Powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell

Currently this works, but I need the SortOnCellColor to be by RGB(255,199,206).

```
$range2 = $ExcelWorkSheet.range("D2")
$range3 = $ExcelWorkSheet.range("E2")

#two-column sort
$ExcelWorkSheet.sort.sortFields.clear()
[void]$ExcelWorkSheet.sort.sortFields.add($range2, $xlSortOnCellColor, $xlAscending,2,1)
[void]$ExcelWorkSheet.sort.sortFields.add($range3, $xlSortOnValues, $xlAscending,`
$xlSortNormal)

$ExcelWorkSheet.sort.setRange($range1)
$ExcelWorkSheet.sort.header = $xlYes
$ExcelWorkSheet.sort.orientation = $xlTopToBottom 
$ExcelWorkSheet.sort.apply()
```

This is how you do it in VBA:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("B1:B25"), _ 
 xlSortOnFontColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255,199,206)
```

[This is what the sort looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUEDL.jpg)

[This is what it needs to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ardf7.jpg)

Comment: your intention is not clear for me, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Your RGB that you want translates to 13551615. Does that help? RRGB is a function you can run to return an integer.

Comment: That doesn't help. I don't know what the line of code to change the Cell Color in the sort is.  In VBA, they make it easy and obvious: .SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255,199,206)